# Generics usage in the gemfire tutorial

Tags: java, generics, gemfire

In this [gemfire tutorial](http://community.gemstone.com/display/gemfire/GemFire+Tutorial#GemFireTutorial-TutorialOverview)

I am not able to interpret this generic declaration:

```
people = cache.<String, Profile>createRegionFactory(REPLICATE)
      .addCacheListener(listener)
      .create("people");
```

What is the significance of the generics the way they have been used in this code snippet?

Comment: I'll admit, I've not seen that generic syntax before either and would be curious to understand what's going on with the `cache.<String, Profile>createRegionFactory(REPLICATE)` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<String, Profile>` after the `cache.` is an explicit type argument. Explicit type arguments are often used when the compiler can't properly infer the type argument, in which case, you explicitly tell it to infer the type argument as the one you passed in the angular brackets before the method name.

For example, suppose you have a method:

```
public <T> void someMethod(T param1, T param2) {
    // body
}
```

Now if you invoke this method as:

```
obj.someMethod(12, "abc");
```

then you would expect that the invocation should give you a compiler error, as you are passing different types to the same type parameter. But it doesn't. In fact, the type `T` is inferred as:

```
T: Object & Serializable & Comparable<? extends Object&Serializable&Comparable<?>>
```

But, you might want compiler to infer the type argument as `Object`. So, how would you do that? There you need an explicit type argument:

```
obj.<Object>someMethod(12, "abc");
```

.. and now the type `T` will be inferred as `Object`.

---

So, in your case, I would guess `createRegionFactory(REPLICATE)` method would be returning a parameterized type with unexpected type parameter, say - `SomeType<Object, Object>`, because the compiler couldn't infer the type parameter, may be because there is not enough context. But you wanted the further method chain - `addCacheListener(listener)` to be invoked on the parameterized type with type parameter `<String, Profile>`.

So, to tell the compiler explicitly to return the parameterized type with a certain type parameter, you give them explicitly with method invocation as:

```
cache.<String, Profile>createRegionFactory(REPLICATE)
     .addCacheListener(listener)...
```

Now, the `addCacheListener(listener)` would be invoked on `SomeType<String, Profile>` instead of `SomeType<Object, Object>`

---

**References:**

- [Java Generics FAQs - Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [What is type argument inference for generic methods?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ401)
  - [What is explicit type argument specification?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ402)
  - [Can I use a wildcard as the explicit type argument of a generic method?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Can%20I%20use%20a%20wildcard%20as%20the%20explicit%20type%20argument%20of%20a%20generic%20method?)